# Error "External table is not in the expected format"

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

here is my code

```
protected void btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string path = @"C:\Users\Mazen\Desktop\Source\Book1.xlsx";
         String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
                                  + "Data Source=" + path + "; "
                                 + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";

         OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn);
         OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
         cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
         connExcel.Open();
         System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSchema;
         dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
         connExcel.Close();

         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
         cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name From [" + SheetName + "]";
         OleDbDataAdapter da = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
         da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
         da.Fill(ds);
}
```

its give an error how to fix it.. If i changed Jet to ACE so its gives an error 
provider is not registered on the local machine. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following for your `strExcelConn`:

```
String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

Comment: its give an error " The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."